# Transition expression when there is no previous route

Tags: angular, animation, transition, router

I've been playing around with angular animations and I recently came across a problem I can't seem to fix. Transition expressions are very useful to go from route A to route B or from any route to route A, etc.. However I can't seem to find the expression needed when I'm transitioning from nothing to route A. For example, if my user access route B with the URL directly instead of going through route A. I'd want a different animation lets say a fade in when the user is not going through route A (use direct URL to route B) but a slide in when he is going trough the normal flow (A => B).

I've tried using 'void => *' and '=> *' but both aren't working.

> routerTransition

```js
    trigger('routerTransition', [
        transition('=> *, Loading => *', [
            query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%', height: '100%' }), {optional: true}),
            group([
                query(
                    ':enter',
                    [
                        style({opacity: 0}),
                        animate('300ms', style({opacity: 1}))
                    ],
                    {optional: true}
                ),
                query(
                    ':leave',
                    [
                        style({opacity: 1}),
                        animate('300ms', style({opacity: 0}))
                    ],
                    {optional: true}
                )
            ])
        ]),
        transition('* => Login', [
            query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%', height: '100%' }), {optional: true}),
            group([
                query(
                    ':enter',
                    [
                        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
                        animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}))
                    ],
                    {optional: true}
                ),
                query(
                    ':leave',
                    [
                        style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}),
                        animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
                    ],
                    {optional: true}
                )
            ])
        ]),
        transition('* <=> *', [
            query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%', height: '100%' }), {optional: true}),
            group([
                query(
                    ':enter',
                    [
                        style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
                        animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}))
                    ],
                    {optional: true}
                ),
                query(
                    ':leave',
                    [
                        style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}),
                        animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
                    ],
                    {optional: true}
                )
            ])
        ])
    ]);
```

> app.component.html

```html
<div [@routerTransition]="animatedRoute(outlet)" class="router">
    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using :increment and :decrement which are not called upon using the direct url. Looks like this.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: LoadingComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: {i: -1}},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: {i: 0}},

    {path: 'client/:client/panel', component: ClientPanelComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: {i: 1}}
];
```

```js
export const routerAnimation = trigger('routerTransition', [
    transition('-1 => *', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%', height: '100%' }), {optional: true}),
        group([
            query(
                ':enter',
                [
                    style({opacity: 0}),
                    animate('300ms', style({opacity: 1}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            ),
            query(
                ':leave',
                [
                    style({opacity: 1}),
                    animate('300ms', style({opacity: 0}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            )
        ])
    ]),
    transition(':decrement', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%', height: '100%' }), {optional: true}),
        group([
            query(
                ':enter',
                [
                    style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
                    animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            ),
            query(
                ':leave',
                [
                    style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}),
                    animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            )
        ])
    ]),
    transition(':increment', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%', height: '100%' }), {optional: true}),
        group([
            query(
                ':enter',
                [
                    style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
                    animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            ),
            query(
                ':leave',
                [
                    style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}),
                    animate('300ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            )
        ])
    ]),
    transition('* <=> *', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%', height: '100%' }), {optional: true}),
        group([
            query(
                ':enter',
                [
                    style({opacity: 0}),
                    animate('300ms', style({opacity: 1}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            ),
            query(
                ':leave',
                [
                    style({opacity: 1}),
                    animate('300ms', style({opacity: 0}))
                ],
                {optional: true}
            )
        ])
    ])
]);
```